How can I copy a range of cells to my actual column?
I have this Excel sheet A:

And this Excel sheet B:

What I need is to copy all content from Excel B sheet from A2 to A6 to the selected cell of sheet A, in this case A1. This would be the result by selecting cells and copy, pasting:

The problem is when the Excel file has 300.000 rows and blank spaces in between. Because CTRL+SHIFT+ARROW KEY won't select until the last row in some cases, neither double clicking the little square at the right-bottom of the cell. And copy & paste gets bugged at some point and it's throwing an error saying the row count doesn't match, when it's obviously matching.
That's why I think that if I can just get a range of cells it should get from the first to last row no matter what is blank or anything.
How can I copy a range of cells to my actual column?

If you are sure about the total row size then you could try this, in the name box write as A1:A300.000 which will select the whole range and now copy and paste the data in the other sheet. Hope this should work.

For selecting, you could use F5 to open the Go To dialog and enter $A$1:$A$300000, and can now do Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V.

A couple of possibilities. Select used range using CTRL + SHIFT + END, then copy, then select only one destination cell, then paste. You could also just right click the sheet tab and select Move or Copy and tick the Copy checkbox. Then rename the resulting sheet.
